# Species Identification: Coniferous tree, Italy

Tags: botany, species-identification

I noticed it close to the place where I work, I live in Italy
Could you tell me the complete name of this tree?

Particular of the leaves
[image: Particular of the leaves (1)]
[image: Particular of the leaves (2)]

[image: tree]
[image: tree [2]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, it looks like a species of [*Taxus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxus) (Yew), for instance [*Taxus baccata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxus_baccata). This is based on the flat needles, "flat" apparence/growth of the branches and the red berries. It's a bit hard to see what the red things are in your 3rd picture though (berries, shoots, flowers??). It should also have reddish bark where you can easily peal of loose scales. They can become very old (>1000y), have been used for many human purposes (woodcarving, medical purposes, bows), and all parts except for the berries are toxic.

[Abies alba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abies_alba) might be an alternative (if the red things are flowers), but then the needle underside should be relatively white and they also look to broad, soft and shiny to me.

Some pictures:
[image: T. baccata needles]
(from wikipedia)

[image: T. baccata branch]
(from http://linnaeus.nrm.se/flora/barr/taxa/taxus/taxubac.html)

[image]
(from wikipedia, a 1200-year-old tree in Poland)